# Idexing in python

Tags: python, function

I am new in programming and I am trying to implement a function that creates a dictionary that maps each term to its **inverted list**.
So, given the collection:

`collection = ["apple orange milk" , "bread milk meat apple" , "apple orange"]`

I want that for each element in the collection to get the index of the string on which it is. I am trying to get the following result:

`inv_ls = { "apple": [0,1,2], "orange": [0,2], "milk":[0,1], "bread":[1], "bread":[1]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your dictionary directly in loop of element

```py
def create_index (C):
        index = {} 
        terms = []
        for element in C:
            terms.append(element.split())
        for i, element in enumerate(terms):
            for term in element:
                if term not in index:
                    index[term] = [i]
                else:
                    index[term].append(i)
        return index

C = ["apple orange milk" , "bread milk meat apple" , "apple orange"]
index = create_index(C)
print(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Split each string in a list of words, then for each word record the index.
If word is not yet appeared, the `setdefault` method creates a new entry in the dict and set an empty list (`[]`).

```py
collection = ["apple orange milk" , "bread milk meat apple" , "apple orange"]
inv_ls = {}

for idx, lst in enumerate([s.split() for s in collection]):
    for item in lst:
        inv_ls.setdefault(item, []).append(idx)
```

```py
>>> inv_ls
{'apple': [0, 1, 2],
 'orange': [0, 2],
 'milk': [0, 1],
 'bread': [1],
 'meat': [1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because terms list is:
`[['apple', 'orange', 'milk'], ['bread', 'milk', 'meat', 'apple'], ['apple', 'orange']]`
which is a list if lists.
So, when you try to find 'apple' in that list compiler gives that ValueError. Correct code should be like:

```
def create_index (C):
    index = {} 
    terms = []
    for element in C:
        terms.append(element.split())
    for element in terms:
        for term in element:
            if term in element:
                index.setdefault(term,[])
                index[term].append(terms.index(element))
    return index
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done using list, set and dict comprehension:

```py
{  # generate dict
    word: [
        string.split(" ").index(word)  # get index
        for string in collection
        if word in string.split(" ")  # if word in string
    ]
    for word in {  # generate set with all words
        word for string in collection for word in string.split(" ")
    }
}
```

You should consider using a fallback value for that all lists have the same length and the index can be used to find the words in the original list.

```py
{  # generate dict
    word: [
        string.split(" ").index(word)  # get index
        if word in string.split(" ")  # if word in string
        else None  # if not in string use a fallback value instead
        for string in collection
    ]
    for word in {  # generate set with all words
        word for string in collection for word in string.split(" ")
    }
}
```

this would produce:

```py
{'bread': [None, 0, None], 'apple': [0, 3, 0], 'milk': [2, 1, None], 'orange': [1, None, 1], 'meat': [None, 2, None]}
```